# Delay when adding emojis to a message on discord (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When I try to add multiple emoji's to a message on discord, there is a slight delay before adding the next one. This is a little annoying and i was wondering if there was any way to add each emoji at the same time.

Snippet of Current Code:

```
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='❌')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0031\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0032\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0033\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0034\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0035\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0036\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0037\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0038\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0039\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u0030\u20E3')
        await client.add_reaction(message=msg,emoji='\u27A1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  There isn't a coroutine for adding more than one reaction to a message at a time because there isn't an endpoint in the discord API for doing it.  Since that means you have to make multiple API calls, the `discord.py` bot is rate-limiting itself to avoid the restrictions of the API.